# Blurry fonts in Intellij on macOS external screen

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I work on MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) with macOS Catalina (10.15.7). I work in GoLand (that is IntelliJ option).

After an update came (and I applied it unfortunately) fonts in IDE became stretched when I open it on an external screen.

I tried to turn change fonts smoothing for IntelliJ but this didn't help.

```
~ defaults write  com.jetbrains.intellij AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
~ defaults write  com.jetbrains.intellij CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -int 0
~ defaults read com.jetbrains.intellij
{
    AppleFontSmoothing = 2;
    CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled = 0;
}
```

I use `JetBrains Mono` font that looks great on a laptop screen but is stretched and not smoothed on external screen.

Is there any idea how to fix it?

[image: external monitor screenshot]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question not related to programing related to a specific tool.

Comment: Hi. Could you please follow https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016827360 to provide the remaining details and file a new issue? Thank you!